# In Swift, NSUserDefaults why does calling setObject require a "forKey:" before second parameter

Tags: ios, swift

When I call `setObject` on `NSUserDefaults` it requires a `forKey:` before it can compile.  But I don't need anything before other methods like `objectForKey` for example.  Why is that?

This works:
`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myString, forKey: "myString")`
This doesn't:
`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myString, "myString")`

This doesn't need a xxx: in front of the first parameter:
`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myString")`

How does one know when to supply a prefixing xxx and a colon before the parameter?  Aside from relying on Xcode's auto-complete or compiler error?

Comment: Apple has really good documentation for swift. Refer here: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I call setObject on NSUserDefaults it requires a forKey: before it can compile. But I don't need anything before other methods like objectForKey for example. Why is that?

The Objective-C method is:

```
-setObject:forKey:
```

it takes two parameters -- the object, and a key. `objectForKey:`, on the other hand, takes only one parameter (the key) and returns an object.

> How does one know when to supply a prefixing xxx and a colon before the parameter? Aside from relying on Xcode's auto-complete or compiler error?

You need to know what method you're calling. You can look that up. For example, the NSUserDefaults documentation provides the Swift prototype for the method you want:

```
func setObject(_ value: AnyObject?,
    forKey defaultName: String)
```

Or, if you happen to know the Objective-C prototype

```
- (void)setObject:(id)value
       forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

it doesn't take long to get the hang of converting in your head.

Comment: I think I might need some clarification on how to read the documentation syntax.  Looking at the second parameter in `func setObject(_ value: AnyObject?, forKey defaultName: String)` I see that:

`String` is the type
`defaultName` is the name of the variable?
`forKey` is ?

Comment: `forKey` is part of the method name. I'm sure it looks strange if you're coming from Java or C, where parameters are simply listed. In Objective-C the parameters are interspersed between parts of the method name, which makes it very easy to remember which parameter goes where. `color(10,15,20)` doesn't tell you which number is which; `colorWithRed:10 green:15 blue:20` does. So that idea carried over into Swift. Give it time if it seems weird -- it's quite a nice convention.

Comment: Ah OK.  You are right, I'm mostly a Java developer.  Prefixing with red, green, blue looks great to me.  I think I was just confused because the first parameter doesn't always have it, which led me to believe there was some esoteric rule I wasn't privy to behind which parameter needed it and which ones didn't.

Comment: Think of the part before the open paren as belonging to the first parameter.  So my example above in Swift would be `colorWithRed(10 green:15 blue:20)`. That's a made-up example, though, just for illustration... the actual method for creating a color in Swift would use an initializer: `UIColor(red:10 green:15 blue:20 alpha:1.0)`

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In swift functions, the first parameter label is not needed (Except for `init` methods). So if a function have only one argument, you don't need to specify the argument label. This is the case why `objectForKey:` doesn't have any label. `setObject:forKey:` needs two argument, so the second argument needs a label.

> By default, the first parameter omits its external name, and the
>   second and subsequent parameters use their local name as their
>   external name. All parameters must have unique local names. Although
>   it’s possible for multiple parameters to have the same external name,
>   unique external names help make your code more readable.

Reference : [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly,
usually you are not required to include the first parameter name when passing an argument to a function.

```
func someFunction(firstParameterName: Int, secondParameterName: Int) {
    // function body goes here
    // firstParameterName and secondParameterName refer to
    // the argument values for the first and second parameters
}
someFunction(1, secondParameterName: 2)
```

> By default, the first parameter omits its external name, and the
> second and subsequent parameters use their local name as their
> external name. All parameters must have unique local names. Although
> it’s possible for multiple parameters to have the same external name,
> unique external names help make your code more readable.

Hope this helps.
You can read more about it here:
[Function Parameter Naming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166)

Comment: That does help.  And the documentation link you provided helps too.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The method/function signature which is

- everything before the opening parenthesis
- everything between a comma and a colon (including the comma and the colon)

is always required.